# Emphasis on 'does' in questions

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across this senentce in a book:

> What *does* your life tell you?

I guess the author italicized "does" in order to emphasise it, but what meaning behind "does" did she want to highlight? The current time, as opposed to *will* or *did*? But if that's the case, shouldn't it be "*is* telling"?

Comment: Why does your mother cook? To feed the children. Yes, but why *does* she cook? To show love. Adding emphasis shows you are looking for the deeper answer to your question.

Comment: Then is it similar to "What does your life really tell you?"

Comment: Yes, *does really* is close.